# Python Unique words in text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, unique

I am in need of inserting unique words into a text file. One word per line and that word will be unique in whole file.

Whenever a new word comes as variable "word" then I need a way to check if it exists in the file. If it exists then it will again pick another word. It will again check if it exists or not and will do so until an unique word comes.

How can I do that?

By the way, I was doing:

```
    newword = "learn"
    f = open('wordlist.txt')
    s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    while s.find(newword) != -1:
        return newword
    else:
        return newword
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RayhaneMama Sorry about not adding test ...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file isn't too large, you could just read it all to memory, and check if the word is there:

```
def word_in_file(filename, word):
    with open(filename) as f:
        words = f.read().splitlines()

    return word in words
```

If you're going to do this more than once, you'd better keep the `words` list and append to it each word you add to the file instead of reading it multiple times.
Additionally, creating a `set` from `words` should improve the search time and may be worth the "effort" if you're adding multiple words to the file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the function and use case please ? I am new...